# Nullability annotations: Array index check is not considered

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, nullable-reference-types

I just found that the nullability annotations fail to correctly recognize an array index check.

```cs
public void Test()
{
    string?[] list = new string[10];
    list[0] = "A";

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] != null)
        {
            list[i].ToString(); // Error: Possible NULL dereferencing.
        }
    }
}
```

Is this just a bug in the analyzer, or is it intentionally reporting the error? I can avoid the error by using a local variable, but it still seems strange.

I'm using .NET 6.0 with `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess *technically*, something could change the reference underneath from another thread. A good bit of defensive programming would be, as you say, using a local variable:

```
var item = list[i];
if (item is not null) {
    item.ToString()
}
```

Also note that `!=` can be overridden. I personally use the pattern matching form `is null` / `is not null`.

If you think the null check in the compiler is wrong, the dotnet Github issues would be a good place to start -- they could at least tell you the exact reasoning.

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues

Comment: The multithreading thing is indeed true, but that's not considered in _any_ of the nullability checks, so that can't really be the reasoning here.  And it obviously doesn't apply here, as all variables are local.

Comment: The error still happens, even if I replace `!=` with `!ReferenceEquals()`